# How to send JSON object as string for email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to send an email with JSON data being pulled in by default, the problem I ma having is in my mail once received I only see the object and not the value. Any ideas?

link to my site : http://wingfield.vmgdemo.co.za/

What I get in my received mail:

```
Make: {{car.make}}
Variant: {{car.variant}}
Year: {{car.year}}
Price: {{car.selling_price}}
```

My input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.drive.make" class="form-control" name="make" id="make" ng-init="vm.drive.make='{{car.make}}'" value="{{car.make}}">
```

My controller for mail:

```
 (function() {
  'use strict';
  var controllerId = 'testDrive';
  var app = angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, testDrive);
  function testDrive($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.drive = {
      name: '',
      number: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      make: '',
      variant: '',
      year: '',
      selling_price: ''
    };
    vm.sendMail = function sendEmail() {
      var driveRequest = '';
      var data = {
        notification: {
          ToList: '',
          CcList: '',
          BccList: '',
          Subject: 'Contact from ' + vm.drive.name,
          Message: vm.drive.message + '\nContact Number: ' + vm.drive.number + '\n\nInterested In:' + '\nID: ' + vm.drive.carid + '\nMake: ' + vm.drive.make + '\nVariant: ' + vm.drive.variant + '\nYear: ' + vm.drive.year + '\nPrice: ' + vm.drive.selling_price,
          MessageSubject: 'Enquiry from ' + vm.drive.name,
          ToName: 'Wingfield Motors',
          FromName: vm.drive.name,
          FromEmail: vm.drive.email
        }
      };

      driveRequest = JSON.stringify(data);

      $.ajax({
        "url": "--REMOVED--",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "accept": "application/json"
        },
        data: driveRequest,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          //
        },
        error: function(response) {
          //
        }
      });
    };
  }

})();
```

Comment: What's the ng-init and value attributes supposed to do?

Comment: Supposed to give me the value of make, variant etc eg Honda, Ballade...I poplate my input on screen the way it should but once i send the mail i get the object? would like to get the value

Comment: Change your `ng-init` to `ng-init="vm.drive.make=car.make"`

Comment: THANK you!!! if you post it as an answer i can approve it :)